# How does neural synchronization happen and what if it doesn’t work like it should in healthy people?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

How does neural synchronization happen and what results/shows up if it doesn’t work like it should like described [here](https://www.intechopen.com/books/research-advances-in-chaos-theory/chaos-in-human-brain-phase-transition):

> Moreover, chaotic behavior stemming from self-organization processes in the human brain could explain “randomness” in neural synchronization related to cognitive functions and consciousness and also in mental disorganization related to psychopathological phenomena such as schizophrenia [14]. In addition, it has been argued that epilepsy is an example of chaos in the human brain [15]. Besides, some researchers think about the dreaming brain as a brain in which some self-organizing processes occur and exhibit chaos-like stochastic properties that are highly sensitive to internal influences [16].

and how can  ["a failure to integrate the activity of local and distributed neural circuits"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2848257/) be described in Layman's terms and without I specifically referring to schizophrenia?

> .. it has been proposed that the cognitive and affective impairments associated with schizophrenia may be related to **a failure to integrate the activity of local and distributed neural circuits**

Comment: Probably better to split up your questions. Also I'd say that first source looks very questionable... I wouldn't say anything they wrote in that quote is wrong, per se, but it looks like the quality of a not-very-good undergraduate paper. The publisher is a predatory publisher that publishes anything submitted for a fee. I'd suggest starting from a more reputable source that may explain better what they are talking about.